# Parameter injection for symfony render_esi (listener instead of static in template)

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-routing

I'm aware that one can add parameters for the esi request like `{{ render_esi('bundle:controller:action', {foo: 'bar'})` (would add the parameter `foo` with the value `bar` to the fragment uri).

My task requires setting this parameter dynamically from outside the template (at the moment the uri is generated).

I could not find an event that would be called as the uri is generated. Google did also not help solving this for me.

Basically what I want is to call `{{ render_esi('bundle:controller:action') }}` and it to result in an esi fragment uri containing the parameter `foo=bar` (added using some service?).

Is there a nice solution for this issue (without overwriting the fragment generators used by symfony that is)?

EDIT:

The parameter is not used by any of the controllers and is more or less required on a global scale as a request-listener will check the parameter and adjust a service with additional information.
The listener will remove the parameter afterwards.

Comment: Have you tried attaching to the kernel with an event listener and checking whether it's an esi request to modify it?

Comment: Once I am inside the esi request itself, I will not have any knowledge about the previous state. That's basically what I need the parameter for.